# Return type conversion from different versions of same library

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, .net-assembly

I'm facing an issue where I feel that the answer should be obvious, but I'm missing something simple and it just escapes me :)

I'm developing an app that must talk to two different versions of Dynamics CRM, this due to migration period overlap.
I chose to implement all business processes using simple data objects  that are CRM version independent and I use two connectors as plugins (separate csproj projects) in which I implement connection/query specific code for each CRM version.

Then I have a mapper project, where I also define an interface that plugins inherit so I can switch them freely. In this mapper I use a factory to instantiate appropriate connector depending on which CRM I want to talk to (decided at runtime), then extract all data I need into data objects and pass them on to business process handlers.

Plugin connectors have to reference appropriate MS Xrm nugets to connect and query respective CRM.
(Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies and Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client)
These libraries are different versions and target different .NET version but contain same namespaces and types (particulary EntityCollection type which is the result of every query)

Because of plugins referencing different XRM libs, the EntityCollection, although being same type in same namespace, originates from different assembly version each time and I need to define this return type in my interface for plugins and be able to retrieve and work with EntityCollection in the mapper disregarding its containing assembly version.

The issues here are the type conversion between same types that reside in different versions of same package, method definition in the interface and the return type, also which library must be referenced in the mapper project to be able to define that interface.

I found this thread
[Type conversion of identical types from different versions of same assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267104/type-conversion-of-identical-types-from-different-versions-of-same-assembly)
that practically states that it's not doable, but I'm not entirely convinced...
What do you think ?

Comment: which exact versions are these Dynamics instances? is this application running on .net core or similar? you mentioned "plugin", can you be more precise about them?

Comment: It's an old version 8.2 running on-prem and we are migrating to Online dynamics Sales Hub with underlying dataverse.

My app is net5 and mapper project is net5 also. 
plugin for the old CRM is .net 4.7 which is required by Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies  nuget 

plugin for the dataverse is .net5 and nuget is the new dataverse client 
https://github.com/microsoft/PowerPlatform-DataverseServiceClient  which is now in preview.
I use simple plugin technique with AssemblyLoadContext and Activator to load DLL's  into mapper project

Comment: "plugin" in Dynamics/Dataverse has a specific meaning, if you don't mean Dynamics/Daverse "plugin" please use another word. Easiest way will be to use for your application .NET framework (4.6.2 or higher) and you can connect to both environments with the same nuget package

Comment: Yes agree, poor choice of "plugin" word  as I have indeed developed a number of Dynamics CRM plugins :)  
I chose PowerPlatform preview client consciously because it will supersede CrmServiceClient and it supports .net5.

Maybe I will have to make do with old client for both environments and rewrite connector using PowerPlatform client after we've migrated fully.... I don't know...

Comment: changes required to upgrade from CrmServiceClient .net framework to ServiceClient .net core/5 are minimum, I don't see a problem if today you still use .net framework for the whole project

Comment: I cannot use .net framework for my entire project. There are parts of the app already written and tested, and whole app is .net5 and it must be so by design.   I thought about what you suggested though and did some tests today.  It appears that I cannot use CrmServiceClient at all in my app neither as a direct reference nor as a plugin dll loaded in at runtime. This is because the SDK is brought into the app's runtime which is .net5 and simply cannot run there.  For the same reason I cannot create any sort of wrapper, so it has now become two problems instead of one I asked about originally

Answer (score 0):

Interesting situation. One idea would be to create a custom class, say `MyEntityCollection`, that you can construct from either type of Microsoft `EntityCollection`.

You could immediately convert any `EntityCollection` you retrieve into this type and deal with only `MyEntityCollection` in the rest of your code.

For example (untested code):

```
public class MyEntityCollection : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    public MyEntityCollection(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityCollection c)
    {
        Entities = c.Entities;
        MoreRecords = c.MoreRecords;
        PagingCookie = c.PagingCookie;
        MinActiveRowVersion = c.MinActiveRowVersion;
        TotalRecordCount = c.TotalRecordCount;
        TotalRecordCountLimitExceeded = c.TotalRecordCountLimitExceeded;
        EntityName = c.EntityName;
        ExtensionData = c.ExtensionData;
    }

    public MyEntityCollection(Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.EntityCollection c)
    {
        Entities = c.Entities;
        MoreRecords = c.MoreRecords;
        PagingCookie = c.PagingCookie;
        MinActiveRowVersion = c.MinActiveRowVersion;
        TotalRecordCount = c.TotalRecordCount;
        TotalRecordCountLimitExceeded = c.TotalRecordCountLimitExceeded;
        EntityName = c.EntityName;
        ExtensionData = c.ExtensionData;
    }

    public DataCollection<Entity> Entities { get; }
    public Entity this[int index] { get; set; }
    public bool MoreRecords { get; set; }
    public string PagingCookie { get; set; }
    public string MinActiveRowVersion { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecordCount { get; set; }
    public bool TotalRecordCountLimitExceeded { get; set; }
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is a great idea, and I have tried that, the problem that arises here is that in order to create this custom class one must reference both variants of Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk package to be able to pass in those constructor param types. 

Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client  is the package name (the nuget), but the assembly inside is named Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk  which conflicts with Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk from older package Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies  nuget.

Comment: In fact, I believe assembly conflict will propagate all the way down, e.g. Entity type in this custom class suffers from the same assembly conflict

Comment: Understood, thanks. Maybe look into using an [extern alias](https://csharp.2000things.com/2012/03/05/532-using-identically-named-types-from-different-assemblies/)

Answer (score 0):

I have now resolved the issue with what one might call a "terrible hack" :-P

The mapper project still targets .NET5 and is now directly referencing the new client library thus having access to Entity and EntityCollection types from the newer sdk.

The plugin that wraps the old Xrm library is no more a plugin but a standalone service app with it's own .Net Framework 4.5 runtime. After a successfull request is made to the on-prem CRM this service serializes the EntityCollection result and sends it to the mapper as Json where it's deserialized into newer version of an EntityCollection using DataContractJsonSerializer

My comparisons have not shown any incompatibilities (yet) so reviving EntityCollection this way works for now.

Now I will have to do the same for OrganizationRequest and I hope it works too :=)

Thanks for your tips and suggestions